# Basic timer with std::thread and std::chrono

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, timer

I'm trying to implement a basic timer with the classic methods: start() and stop(). I'm using c++11 with std::thread and std::chrono.

- Start method. Creates a new thread that is asleep for a given interval time, then execute a given std::function. This process is repeated while a 'running' flag is true.
- Stop method. Just sets the 'running' flag to false.

I created and started a Timer object that show "Hello!" every second, then with other thread I try to stop the timer but I can't. The Timer never stops.

I think the problem is with th.join()[*] that stops execution until the thread has finished, but when I remove th.join() line obviously the program finishes before the timer start to count.

So, my question is how to run a thread without stop other threads?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class Timer
{
    thread th;
    bool running = false;

public:
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Interval;
    typedef std::function<void(void)> Timeout;

    void start(const Interval &interval,
               const Timeout &timeout)
    {
        running = true;

        th = thread([=]()
        {
            while (running == true) {
                this_thread::sleep_for(interval);
                timeout();
            }
        });

// [*]
        th.join();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        running = false;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Timer tHello;
    tHello.start(chrono::milliseconds(1000),
                 []()
    {
        cout << "Hello!" << endl;
    });

    thread th([&]()
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
        tHello.stop();
    });

    th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello!
Hello!
...
...
...
Hello!
```

Comment: As a side comment, in my experience trying to do the same, using condition_variable was more efficient (because it's designed for this kind of thing). However it makes the code less clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `Timer::start`, you create a new thread in `th` and then immediately `join` it with `th.join()`. Effectively, `start` won't return until that spawned thread exits. Of course, it won't ever exit because nothing will set running to false until after `start` returns...

Don't `join` a thread until you intend to wait for it to finish. In this case, in `stop` after setting `running = false` is probably the correct place.

Also - although it's not incorrect - there's no need to make another thread in `main` to call `this_thread::sleep_for`. You can simply do so with the main thread:

```
int main()
{
    Timer tHello;
    tHello.start(chrono::milliseconds(1000), []{
        cout << "Hello!" << endl;
    });

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
    tHello.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing the `join` in `start` place it after `running = false` in `stop`. Then the stop method will effectively wait until the thread is completed before returning.