# Timer with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I'm working on a timer class to perform operations on a different thread, sample code below is a copy from another SO question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521282/basic-timer-with-stdthread-and-stdchrono)

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

class Timer
{
public:
    ~Timer();
    Timer() noexcept;

    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Interval;
    typedef std::function<void(void)> Timeout;

public:
    void start(const Interval& interval, const Timeout& timeout);
    void stop();

private:
    std::thread mThread;    /** Timer thread */
    bool mRunning = false;  /** Timer status */
};
```

Implementation with a comment where the problem will occur:

```
Timer::~Timer()
{
}

Timer::Timer() noexcept
{
}

void Timer::start(const Interval& interval, const Timeout& timeout)
{
    mRunning = true;

    mThread = std::thread([&]()
        {
            while (mRunning == true)
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);

                // std::abort will be called here
                timeout();
            }
        });
}

void Timer::stop()
{
    mRunning = false;
    mThread.join();
}
```

Sample to test the timer:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Timer tm;

    tm.start(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000), []
        {
            std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
        });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
    tm.stop();
}
```

I'm not able to understand why `std::abort` is called while executing the `std::function` within lambda and how do I resolve this?

Comment: You are saving a reference to a temp object which gets destroyed before you have a chance to call your `timeout`.

Comment: That's not the only issue though: You also need to make `mRunning` atomic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments to your `start` function are passed by reference. In your lambda, you capture them by reference. By the time you come around calling that lambda, everything you've captured is destroyed, thus you're causing undefined behavior.

Additionally, make sure to either use `atomic<bool>` instead of a regular `bool`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdio>
#include <atomic>

class Timer {
public:
    ~Timer() {
        if (mRunning) {
            stop();
        }
    }
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Interval;
    typedef std::function<void(void)> Timeout;

    void start(const Interval &interval, const Timeout &timeout) {
        mRunning = true;

        mThread = std::thread([this, interval, timeout] {
            while (mRunning) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);

                timeout();
            }
        });
    }
    void stop() {
        mRunning = false;
        mThread.join();
    }

private:
    std::thread mThread{};
    std::atomic_bool mRunning{};
};

int main() {
    Timer tm;

    tm.start(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000), [] {
        std::puts("Hello!");
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
}
```

P.S. you might want to look into coroutines depending on where this idea is going.

Comment: I tried without references with `Timer::start(Interval interval, Timeout timeout)` this doesn't abort however it doesn't stop the timer either, sample fix code would be welcome.

Comment: @metablaster Make sure to capture it by value `[=]` instead of `[&]`.

Comment: Capturing lambda by value and atomic `mRunning` made things work, thanks a lot.